# moving turtlebot in simulation using a C++ program

Tags: simulation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to learn, how to move turtlebot in simulation using a c++ program. I am following [ROS Tutorial Part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlyaXVruKZA). However, the tutorial used electric while I am using hydro. As there is no turtlebot_key.cpp in hydro, I collected it from [this site](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/hydro/turtlebot_teleop/src/turtlebot_key.cpp). I Used roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch and made the node executed. It is showing the following message.

Reading from keyboard

---------------------------.

Use arrow keys to move the turtlebot.

However turtlebot in gazebo doesn't move. I wish to know, does turtlebot_key.cpp work in hydro? Do I need to change it?
Your help is highly appreciated.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200509/moving-turtlebot-in-simulation-using-a-c++-program/) by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use teleop for moving the turtlebot around using keyboard in gazebo.
Use:

$ roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch

---

Originally posted by [pronik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13416/pronik/) with karma: 30 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2015-01-07**:
Yes, I can use this. However I want to see the code (C++) so that I can learn and modify the code to control the turtlebot. I would like to ask if someone has the code.
Thank you

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-08**:
The code is [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/indigo/turtlebot_teleop).

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2015-01-15**:
Thank you.